# iOS how can I get CLLocation in persistent state

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocation

I'm trying to get a CLLocation property to store a location MKMapView. this part of my code:

on my .h

@property (retain, nonatomic) CLLocation *currentlocation;

on my .m

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{

    if ((_currentlocation.coordinate.longitude == 0 ) && (_currentlocation.coordinate.latitude == 0) )
    {
        self.currentlocation = [self.mapView.userLocation.location copy];
}
```

The problem is every time is trying to update the location the "self.currentlocation" is 0. My question how can I retain the value of self.currentlocation ?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is the `self.currentlocation = ...` line actually executing?  Comparing floating-point values like that is unreliable.  Instead, check if _currentLocation is nil.  This is what David P is saying (that the `if` condition doesn't work).

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the 0 with "nil". 
Now the if statement checks, if your variable is empty and not if it is 0.

Comment: I don't think you understood my question.My problem is I want to keep the value on self.currentlocation.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem using CLLocationCoordinate2D to store the coordenates store in self.mapView.userLocation.location.